# Enable menu Strip in child form using c#

Tags: c#, winforms

how to enable menu strip in child form?

i just want to enable the menu button strip when i will close the child form
how to code that in child form?

Student....

```
private void tsmNewEmp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(NewEmp == null)
    {
        NewEmp = new NewEmployee();
        NewEmp.MdiParent = this;
    }
    NewEmp.Show();
    tsmNewEmp.Enabled = false;
    tsmNewContract.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [FormClosed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event to update the buttons in the parent form after the child is closed:

```
private void tsmNewEmp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(NewEmp == null)
    {
        NewEmp = new NewEmployee();
        NewEmp.MdiParent = this;
        NewEmp.FormClosed += FormClosed_1;
    }
    NewEmp.Show();
    tsmNewEmp.Enabled = false;
    tsmNewContract.Enabled = false;
}

private void FormClosed_1(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    tsmNewEmp.Enabled = true;
    tsmNewContract.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: i try this but i can't see the button in parent menustrip  from the child form.

Comment: The code I posted does the enabling in the parent form. Why do you want to do it in the child form?

Comment: Yes i want to do it in child Form after i will close the child form it will enable the tsmNewEmp and tsmNewContract. this possible?

Comment: That is what this code is doing (except that it is event based and done in parent form). Did you try it?

Comment: private void FormClosed_1(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            tsmNewEmp.Enabled = true;
            tsmNewContract.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void tsmNewEmp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
           if(NewEmp == null)
           {
               NewEmp = new NewEmployee();
               NewEmp.MdiParent = this;
               NewEmp.FormClosed += FormClosed_1;
           }
           NewEmp.Show();
           tsmNewContract.Enabled = false;
           tsmNewEmp.Enabled = false;
        }

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand why you post my code again. I answered to what has been described in your question and it should solve your problem. If it doesn't fit to your problem please edit your question and give additional details/code. Otherwise I can't help you any further.

Comment: sorry @fabian i did not put any comment actually i try it but the same problem i got tsmNewEmp and tsmNewContract still disabled.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint to see if the code is hit when you close the form NewEmp ?

Answer (score 0):

Control[] controls = this.MdiParent.Controls.Find("Menu", true);
            foreach (Control ctrl in controls)
            {
                if (ctrl.Name == "Menu")
                {
                    MenuStrip strip = ctrl as MenuStrip;
                    strip.Items["login"].Enabled = false;
                    strip.Items["logout"].Enabled = false;
                }
            }

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer. 
@EktaMakadiya Question?